# What is proper way to pass data between Nest.JS API and React Web

Tags: typescript, serialization, nestjs, typeorm

I started learning Nest.JS, I chose TypeORM as Backend ORM and React on Frontend (if it is important).

I want to know, what are the best ways to communicate (send data).
For now, I have an TypeORM Entity:

```
@Entity({
  schema: 'security',
  name: 'user',
})
export class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    unique: true,
  })
  public email: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
  })
  public firstName: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
  })
  public lastName: string;
...
}
```

Service with DB data fetching:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private hashService: HashService) {}

  public create = async (user: UserCreateDto): Promise<UserEntity> => {
    const { password, ...data } = user;

    return UserEntity.create({
      password: await this.hashService.hash(user.password),
      ...data,
    }).save();
  };

  public findById = async (id: number): Promise<UserEntity> => {
    return UserEntity.findOne({
      where: {
        id,
      },
      relations: ['role'],
    });
  };
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  public constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() body: UserCreateDto): Promise<UserResponseDto> {
    return this.userService.create(body);
  }

  @Get(':id')
  async findById(
    @Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,
  ): Promise<UserResponseDto> {
    return this.userService.findById(id);
  }
}
```

Validating with UserCreateDto works fine, but UserResponseDto gives me some issues:

```
@Exclude()
export class UserResponseDto {
  @Expose()
  public id: number;

  @Expose()
  public email: string;

  @Expose()
  public firstName: string;

  @Expose()
  public lastName: string;
  ...
}
```

Even if the fields like password are not present in this dto, I have all fields of entity in my postman response. I tried to implicitly @Exclude password field, but it didn't work too.

I tried to add GlobalInterceptor:

```
 app.useGlobalInterceptors(
    new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector), {
      strategy: 'excludeAll',
      excludeExtraneousValues: true,
      exposeDefaultValues: true,
      exposeUnsetFields: true,
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    }),
  );
```

But it either makes response body empty or returns all field (tried different options).

How should I configure serialization or should I do something else?

Comment: You would have manually convert objects from UserEntity to UserResponseDto Or use an auto mapper like https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/nestjs

Answer (score 0):

You're returning structurally a similar object to `UserResponseDto`, but that won't make the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` work, because `class-transformer` (what the interceptor uses) needs to have a class instance so that it can read the metadata of the class to know what to return. You either need to manually map the entity retrieved to a DTO, or you need to use a solution like an [automapper](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/nestjs).